# Online Unicode renderer

Tags: web-apps, hosted, unicode

Sometimes I have texts with Unicode characters not known to my system (using Ubuntu I already have a plethora of fonts installed by default, but there are still unknown characters in the world).

Is there an online tool that would render short Unicode / UTF8 input texts with good character availability?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Uniview](https://r12a.github.io/uniview/) can show characters as a graphic, hence it will work regardless of fonts installed on your system (as the browser needs the fonts too to display characters as characters and not images)

Comment: So far, it seems nice. Well, only time using it will tell the character coverage.

Comment: @dronus It is updated each time a new Unicode version goes out. See "UniView 14" in header right now that shows it supports version 14 of Unicode standard. In filter tab you can select "show age" to see the Unicode version where each character was added.